# How to run Django FSM first project

Tags: python, django, django-fsm

I have below django-program--- walk.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django_fsm import transition, FSMIntegerField
    from django_fsm import FSMField, transition
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
    import django
    django.setup()

    from django.core.management import call_command
    class Order(models.Model):
         STATUS_GO = 0
         STATUS_COME =1
         STATUS_CHOICES = (
          (STATUS_GO, 'GO'),
          (STATUS_COME,'come')
           )
    product = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = FSMIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_GO, protected=True)


   @transition(field=status, source=[STATUS_GO],  target=STATUS_COME)
   def walk(self):
       print("Target moved")
```

Above code is available in c:\Hello folder.

I have  referred few blogs & link for creating new django project.

so in cmd window, dragged to above folder by "cd c:\Hello" & executed:

```
 django-admin startproject mysite
```

And moved walk.py into mysite folder

And the directory as :

```
       Hello/
             mysite/
             manage.py
             walk.py
                      mysite/
                      __init__.py
                      settings.py
                      urls.py
                      wsgi.py
```

And Later executed:

```
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py runserver
```

Post which i have been stuck now  & confused above two steps is required for my project.

Do

```
    python manage.py startapp polls
```

is mandate to run now ? If so, what to edit in polls/models.py file ??

Later what do i need to mention in INSTALLED_APPS =  [] ???

And keep moving further, where do i place my project walk.py in above directory ?

Now when i run the walk.py , i could see below issue now:

RuntimeError: Model class **main**.Order doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Pls any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actual error :**
RuntimeError: Model class **main**.Tag doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

**my Solution:**

run

```
   django-admin startproject mysite
```

in the project folder

```
    Hello/
         mysite/
         manage.py
         walk.py
                  mysite/
                  __init__.py
                  settings.py
                  urls.py
                  wsgi.py
```

Later added ' **main**' in INSTALLED_APPS & works fine now

Answer (score 1):

In `INSTALLED_APPS` you will have to add the new app like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    // ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'polls'
]
```

Now Django will be aware of your app.